# Node.js & Node-Postgres: Putting Queries into Models

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I would like to 'functionalize' my queries by putting them into functions which have apt names for the task.

I want to avoid putting everything in the `req, res` functions (my controllers), and instead put them in 'models' of sorts, that is, another JavaScript file that will be imported and used to run the functions that execute queries and return the results on behalf of the controller.

Assuming that I have the following setup for the queries:

**UserController.js**

```
exports.userAccount = function(req, res, next) {
    var queryText = "\
        SELECT  *\
        FROM    users\
        WHERE id = $1\
        ";

    var queryValues = [168];

    pg.connect(secrets.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {

        client.query(queryText, queryValues, function(err, result) {

        res.render('pathToSome/page', {
                queryResult: result.rows
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Here, while I'm in the query, I essentially redirect and render a page with the data. That works fine. But I want to take out all that `pg.connect` and `client.query` code and move it to a separate file to be imported as a model. I've come up with the following:

**UserModel.js**

```
exports.findUser = function(id) {

    // The user to be returned from the query
    // Local scope to 'findUser' function?
    var user = {};

    var queryText = "\
        SELECT  *\
        FROM    users\
        WHERE id = $1\
        ";

    var queryValues = [id];

    pg.connect(secrets.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {

        client.query(queryText, queryValues, function(err, result) {

        // There is only ever 1 row returned, so get the first one in the array
        // Apparently this is local scope to 'client.query'?
        // I want this to overwrite the user variable declared at the top of the function
        user = result.rows;

        // Console output correct; I have my one user
        console.log("User data: " + JSON.stringify(user));
        });
    });

    // I expect this to be correct. User is empty, because it was not really
    // assigned in the user = result.rows call above.
    console.log("User outside of 'pg.connect': " + JSON.stringify(user));

    // I would like to return the user here, but it's empty!
    return user;
};
```

and I'm calling my model function as so:

```
var user = UserModel.findUser(req.user.id);
```

The query executes perfectly fine in this fashion - except that the `user` object is not being assigned correctly (I'm assuming a *scope* issue), and I can't figure it out.

The goal is to be able to call a function (like the one above) from the controller, have the model execute the query and return the result to the controller.

Am I missing something blatantly obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgconnect` is an asynchronous call. Instead of waiting for data to return from the database before proceeding with the next line, it goes ahead with the rest of the program before Postgres answers. So in the code above, `findUser` returns a variable that has not yet been populated.

In order to make it work correctly, you have to add a callback to the `findUser` function. (I told you wrong in a previous edit: The `done` parameter in pg.connect is called in order to release the connection back to the connection pool.) The final result should look something like this:

```
exports.findUser = function(id, callback) {
    var user = {};
    var queryText = "SELECT  FROM users WHERE id = $1";
    var queryValues = [id];
    pg.connect(secrets.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
        client.query(queryText, queryValues, function(err, result) {
            user = result.rows;
            done(); // Releases the connection back to the connection pool
            callback(err, user);
        });
    });
    return user;
};
```

And you'd use it, not like this:

```
var user = myModule.findUser(id);
```

But like this:

```
myModule.findUser(id, function(err, user){
    // do something with the user.
});
```

If you have several steps to perform, each of them dependent on data from a previous asynchronous call, you'll wind up with confusing, Inception-style nested callbacks. Several asynchronous libraries exist to help you with making such code more readable, but the most popular is npm's `async` module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I forgot about the `done` call; however, outside of the `pg.connect` function I'm still getting an empty `user` object. I'm just not sure what the correct way is to get the result from `pg.connect`/`client.query` is... One would think that `done(results)` would do it, but that's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: Since findUser contains an asynchronous method, that makes it asynchronous as well, so you can't use it to assign to a variable like `var user = findUser(id)`. It needs a callback as well. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Brilliant! I guess I just didn't understand the concept of async tasks. I was thinking about using the `async` module in this project, but there isn't enough *need* for it. I also didn't see anything about async in the `node-postgres` wiki (documentation), so I didn't know where to start. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I know this is an old post...but I wondered why there is a 'return user' given as the last statement...I would think this is redundant given that 'user' is being sent in the callback...?  Just curious  :)  Seems to be a very nice bit of code, I intend on using it.